# cf API endpoint for UI console https://console.w3ibm.bluemix.net/

Tags: ibm-cloud

How do i find the API Endpoint for IBM dedicated bluemix ?

UI Console = https://console.w3ibm.bluemix.net/

Comment: Questions about internal systems shouldn't be asked in public places. Try replacing "console" with"api".

Answer (score 0):

CF API endpoint:   https://api.w3ibm.bluemix.net (API version: 2.106.0)